# Blender add-on "3D Print Toolbox" and MeshLab

Tags: blender, meshlab

Blender software has a nice mesh analysis add-on called ”3D Print Toolbox". It is making us give it a second look for our 3D printing workflow.

On the other hand, MeshLab is very nice to have mesh repair tools.

I see the errors in the Blender, and then I close the program. And then I open MeshLab and make the corrections. The goal is to produce the model with a 3D printer.

Is there a possibility to do the analysis in MeshLab as well? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the "Compute Topological Measures" filter, found under "Quality Measure and Computations". This will tell you if the mesh is manifold, if it has any boundary edges (i.e. holes) and how many components it is composed of (usually should be just one for 3D printing).

The visualizations are also very useful to show most errors real-time, including highlighting boundary edges, non-manifold edges and vertices. When you apply your repair filters (such as "Merge close vertices" or "close holes") you will see the results immediately in the overlay and highlighting.